# OpenOffice.org calc cannot read flex export xls using as3xls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, excel

I have tried flex data grid export xls using as3xls library .when i open using microsoft office it's opening fine. but if i tried to read from openoffice.org calc , not working properly .May i know why not working ,   So Any one know idea to export xls from flex for read calc .please let me know .
 I tried below code for export excel .

```
var xls:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
xls.sheets.addItem(sheet);
var bytes:ByteArray = xls.saveToByteArray();
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,fileReference_Complete);
fileReference.save(bytes, filename);
```

Comment: Most likely the issue is with the underlying file format created by the library; not your code that uses the library to create the file.

Comment: is there any sample  code to  export excel for open office calc . please let me know .it's helpful to me thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

My github project only reads xlsx, but it should work fine with open office files https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader